# CSS to create offset highlighted text

Tags: css

I am attempting to use CSS to highlight text, but to have the highlighting offset as in this example:

[image: Offset highlighted text]

I've accomplished this partially by using a linear gradient with the top half of the gradient transparent:

```html
.menu-highlight
{
 background: linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(255,255,255,0) 45%, #FFFFFF 45%) right;
 display: inline;
}
```

However, what I am left with is this:

[image: Output of current code]

Any ideas on what I can add to accomplish the offset?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: an inset box-shadow maybe?

Answer (score 2):

You can do lots of things with pseudo-elements:

```css
div {
  padding: 12px 36px;
  background-color: #DBDCDE;
}

.beautiful-link {
  font-weight: 1000;
  color: #999A9C;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.beautiful-link::before {
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translate(-8px, 4px);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="beautiful-link" href="#">BUSINESS</p>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! What I am trying to do is use this for styling a menu in Wordpress. There is an option to specify a CSS class for a particular menu item, so ideally I'd like to define a class that will do this. Is it possible to translate the above (or something similar) into a class?

Comment: I just edited the code to meet your requirements. You can use any class or element you want. @transit54

Comment: Any way to make it work with multiline text?

Answer (score 0):

Use `box-shadow` for this:

```css
.box {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px 20px 15px;
}

.highlight  {
  box-shadow:0 2px 0 16px inset grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">some text</div>
<div class="box highlight">some text</div>
```

Comment: I really appreciate it! Box-shadow definitely provides the needed offset. Unfortunately, the background is still running beyond the end of the text. It looks like I'll need to add <span> tags within the menu to limit the background to just the width of the text.

Comment: @transit54 so you need it above the text? I can edi this if you want

Comment: @transit54 box-shadow seems a good solution here : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/jObxeNV , tweak it to your needs to find out.